# comma delimited list of numbers and grouping the numbers into they are sequential arrange

Tags: java

the question was write a program the will do the comma delimited list of numbers,grouping the numbers into a range when they are sequential.
 given the  Input:

```
1,2,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,31
```

and expected output:

```
"[[1],[2], [6,7,8], [13,14,15], [21-25], [32]]"
```

and i wrote a simple code like this

```
public static void main(String []args){
        String input = "1,3,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,31";
        String []num = input .split(",");
        String temp = "[";
        int min = 1;
            for(int i =0; i <num.length;i++){
                if(num[1] == num[0]){
                    temp = temp + num[i]+"]";
                }else if (num[min+1] != num[i]){
                    temp = temp + "," +num[i];
                }else{
                    temp = "]";
                }
                System.out.print(temp);
            }
    }
```

when i run this code it give me the following 
output:

```
[,1[,1,3]],7],7,8],7,8,9],7,8,9,12],7,8,9,12,13],7,8,9,12,13,14],7,8,9,12,13,14,15],7,8,9,12,13,14,15,21],7,8,9,12,13,14,15,21,22],7,8,9,12,13,14,15,21,22,23],7,8,9,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24],7,8,9,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25],7,8,9,12,13,14,15,21,22,23,24,25,31]
```

Comment: `if(num[1] == num[0]){` looks wrong.  Why are you always checking [0] and [1]?

Comment: you have to compare strings with .equals not with ==, but it seems you have another problem not just this

Comment: Your expected output looks really weird. Why `[1],[2]` and not `[1,2]`? Why `[21-25]` and not `[21,22,23,24,25]`? Or why `[13,14,15]` and not `[13-15]`? What are the actual rules? Furthermore, your expectation ends with `[32]` but your input ends with `31` - is it a typo?

Comment: if(num[i] !=null){ i also did try it this way

Comment: my mistake is 3 not 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a homework? Try at your best to solve homework yourself!

I think one of your problems is that you handle the numbers as strings, and the comparison of the strings only compares the references!
Consider the following code:

```
String a =  new String("1");
String b = "1";

System.out.println("a: "+a+" b: "+b);
System.out.println(a==b);
```

The output is following:

```
a: 1 b: 1
false
```

Even though the strings have exactly the same contents, they do not refer to the same object, so you cannot be sure that the strings that you compare are equal! Strings should be compared with `equals()` method.

You should anyway first transform the numbers into int[] array by doing

```
String[] strs = input.split(",");

int[] ints = new int[strs.length()];
for(int i = 0;i<ints.length;i++){
    ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
}
```

Or by using functional elements in java 8:

```
int[] integers = Arrays.stream(input.split(",")).map(Integer::parseInt).mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
```

Then you can compare them and be 100% sure the comparison is right.